# Remote Debugging on Windows 10 Home Edition with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, remote-debugging

I have been trying to do remote debugging from Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 on a Windows Server 2008 to debug a program on Windows 10 Home Edition. I seem to be not able to connect to the msvsmon.exe on Windows 10. The error I keep getting is

"Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor named "XXXXXXXXX". Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."

I have checked the credentials and also ran msvsmon.exe on the remote computer with no security warn and also setting the msvsmon to allow connections to anyone. However, it still does not seem to work.

Does Windows 10 home edition not work for remote debugging?

Comment: Seeing as remote desktop is not included with windows 10 Home Edition, you will need to find the right packages and install them similar to how IIS is [installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048420/iis-windows-authentication-is-missing-at-windows-10-asp-net-visual-studio-2015?rq=1)