# iis windows authentication is missing at windows 10 (ASP.NET Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, iis-7

I am trying to run an asp .net website in Visual Studio 2015 that is using windows authentication in IIS7. Although I installed IIS in my PC, while trying to add "windows authentication" from

> Control Panel-> Turn Windows features on or off-> Internet Information
>   Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Security

it seems that this feature is missing from the list.

Have a look at the picture.

[image]

What other options do I have in order to run the project via windows authentication?

Comment: facing same problem. Please provide some help.

Answer (score 86):

Windows 10 Home edition doesn't include Windows Authentication (and a bunch of other IIS security features). However, the package with these features is sitting right there in your OS and you can manually install it.

All you need to do is open an elevated command prompt and run:

> dism /online /norestart /add-package:%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.16299.15.mum

- *Filename above may be slightly different since it's based on system bitness and version*

Then just make your way back to:

> Turn Windows features on or off > Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Security

All the "pro" options under Security will be available. Simply check "Windows Authentication" and reboot.

Comment: @coldfused would you happen to know if there are any other packages needed to be installed for say performance profiling, I have a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375796/run-performance-profile-on-windows-10-home-edition) that I used your answer for

Comment: Package version can differ if Windows was updated. You can go to %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages folder and look for a newer file. For me it was: Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1.mum

Comment: for me Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17763.1

Comment: As @elshev mentioned, you have to check the package version before you execute the command. For me Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1.mum (Windows 10)

Comment: For anyone seeing multiple versions of the package, picking the very last one (ordered by file date) works.

Comment: @coldfused you're a genuis! would love to know how you figured that out!

Comment: I had to remove  `/norestart` but otherwise this worked perfectly

Comment: It should be noted that systemroot is usually the C:/ drive. The actual file can be found by checking the directory

Comment: Have anyone tried that on windows 11? I've installed some of this .mum packages, but "Windows Authentication" option does not show on "Add Windows Features"...

Comment: I confirm, It works on Windows 11

Comment: For me in windows 11 the file name was different : dism /online /norestart /add-package:%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.22621.2506.mum

Answer (score 10):

Windows 10 Home edition does not support windows authentication in IIS. Once you upgrade to Windows 10 Pro, you will see several additional features in IIS, including windows authentication.

Comment: thank you very much! I couldn't find an answer until now

Answer (score 6):

Check if this feature is deployed:

At appwiz.cpl, select 'Turn Windows Features on or off', verify if
Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Security -> Windows Authentication is selected.

[image]

Comment: Where is the forms authentication?

Answer (score -2):

Just rightclick on IIS and click open as  'Adminstrator'. Retry the same. It should work

Answer (score -3):

To enable “Windows Authentication” either you need to upgrade the OS to Pro version or you can run this command to enable it.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism /online /norestart /add-package:%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17134.1.mum

The file name will be different based on windows updates. So please update if requires.