# IIS windows authentication install difficulties

Tags: windows, authentication, iis, mds

I am trying to install Master Data Service MSD on my local machine. Theorically there are 3 steps :

- pre-installation tasks
- Installation tasks
- post-Installation tasks

During the pre-installation tasks we verify the installation requirements.

The Master Data Services web application needs some Windows Web Server roles and role services. Among these services we have the "Windows Authentication" (under Security).

The problem is that I did not find under security node `Windows Authentication`. Instead I find `Basic Authentication`.

My OS is Windows 10.

To install (add) the the desired roles I follow the theoritical instructions:

`Control panel| Programs and features| turn Windows Featues on or off`. I then expand `Security` under `World Wide Web Services` but there is no Windows authentication among the check boxes, there is only basic authentication.

Also when I open IIS and double click Authentication pane there are 4 Authentication (`basic, anonymous,ASP.net impersonation and formular`), so again, I don't find `windows Authentication`.

I read some suggestions on the internet telling that we can edit the applicationHost.config file. I find 2 file on different paths.

The location of the first one is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\AppServer`

and the second location is: `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`

In those files I replace `<windowsAuthentication />` under

`<security><authentication>` node by :

```
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
                <providers>
                    <add value="Negotiate" />
                    <add value="NTLM" />
                </providers>
            </windowsAuthentication>
```

and I also add `<add name="WindowsAuthenticationModule" lockItem="true" />` under `<system.webServer><modules>`

I did this on the 2 files because I was not sure whether it should be done only on the latter one or not (iis and not iisexpess). But even with those changes it does not work and what surprise me is that when I open iis after editing file, I also don't find windows aythentication among the authentication list in Authentication pane. So I conclude that editing did not serve at all and make no change to IIS.

Of course because I failed to enable Windows Authentication when I open MDS (to do the installation step), I get a warning error telling that IIS is not configured correctly because windows authentication is not installed on this server.

Comment: You probably need a higher edition of windows in order to enable windows authentication. What edition do you have now? Home?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iis windows authentication is missing at windows 10 (ASP.NET Visual Studio 2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048420/iis-windows-authentication-is-missing-at-windows-10-asp-net-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 0):

You'll find here how to add it and after that you'll be able to use it:
https://weblogs.asp.net/zroiy/missing-windows-authentication-provider-for-iis-7-on-windows-server-2008

Comment: Hello DJPillowhead. As I said in my description that in  Windows Web Server roles under Security node there is only Basic Authentication suggesting among the check boxes, there is no Windows Authentication!! And that is what surprise me!!