# Run Performance Profile On Windows 10 Home Edition

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio-2017, profiler

I'm trying to run the visual studio 2017 profiler for IIS Express on Windows 10 But I'm running into some trouble.

When I tried to install all the required IIS Component's I Noticed that I was missing a few because I was running Windows 10 Home Edition I found a solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48197001/1938988)

> dism /online /norestart /add-package:%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-AddOn-2-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.16299.15.mum

After I ran that I was pretty much able to install all the supposed required components for running the profiler

[image]

Despite that when ever I try to run the Performance Profile I still receive an error:

> localhost:50936 is a remote or invalid website, profiling is only support for local websites

**Edit** 
I've updated the computer to run windows 10 Pro Edition, Yet I'm still getting this error

I checked my event logs for windows and I see an error from Visual Studio Profiler:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The method or operation is not implemented., System.Object get_Value()
>      at EnvDTE.Property.get_Value()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PerformanceTools.ProjectTarget.LoadBinaryProject(IVsHierarchy hier)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PerformanceTools.ProjectTarget.LoadProjInfo()

Does anyone know if there are any other packages I need to install to get the profiler running?

Comment: Are you looking to use something other than what is displayed in Diagnostic Tools Window in VS2017?  If yes, then which one.

Comment: @Photo_tom I'm trying to profile IIS Neither Diagnostic Tools Nor Performance Profiler is Working.  This question is specifically for Performance Profiler.

Comment: I'm trying to just profile my WebApi which is running on IIS Express,  I've also tried it published as well

Comment: I'm assuming that you are looking at a time based measurement.  If this is correct, then take a look at MiniProfiler at https://miniprofiler.com/.  It works great with MVC.

Comment: @photo_tom thanks.  Do you know if that can profile the entire pipeline including the DI Container and Model Binders?

Comment: You will want to install https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.Mvc4/.   This adds most of the events into the profiling.

Comment: I've encountered a similar looking exception info on Application logs error messages:  
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
   at EnvDTE.Property.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.ProjectRuleSetNode..ctor                                                       This happens when I select Debug from Configuration combobox on Code Analysis properties window. VS freezes and crashes and then restarts.      
Here is the ss :  https://ibb.co/HXP7NJc                       
I don't know if I should open a new  question for this.