# windows authentication not showing up in iis windows 10

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7, windows-10, windows-authentication

**I am trying to use windows authentication in my application.**
**I am not seeing the windows authentication option in the iis and control panel.**

[image]

[image]

**Can anyone let me know how  can i enable windows authentication in windows 10**

Comment: Which edition it's ??

Comment: Windows 10 home

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048420/iis-windows-authentication-is-missing-at-windows-10-asp-net-visual-studio-2015?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to have professional or enterprise version for enabling the windows authentication.