# Can't install windows authentication on windows 11

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I've installed and configured windows authentication on iis and windows before (local dev machine), using steps like this: [iis windows authentication is missing at windows 10 (ASP.NET Visual Studio 2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048420/iis-windows-authentication-is-missing-at-windows-10-asp-net-visual-studio-2015)

- installed iis additional features using dism command line utility
- selected Windows authentication on "Add or remove windows features" (free translation from portuguese)
- configured It on iis

But now I'm trying to do It on windows 11, and It seems the first step is not working. I've already installed some of the packages available in c:\windows\servicing\packages, but none of them makes the windows authentication option to appear in "Turn Windows features...".

Has anyone configured windows authentication on windows 11?

Comment: If Microsoft finally decided to remove that completely from Home editions, your only option is to upgrade to Pro editions.

Comment: You say you're using DISM command line utility....but what command are you using? Kind of essential information. Perhaps the command is just different for Windows 11 - that's speculation on my part. You should also clarify what edition of Windows 11 you are using.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this problem? I am also having the same issue, I cannot find the  Windows Authentication checkbox in my Add/Remove Features. My OS is `Windows 11 Home Single Language`